# WP E-commerce display issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP-e-commerce on  a page and I've added around 30 products but WP-eCommerce displays just 10 products I've checked the short code and everything seem to be fine. Even when it shows it doesn't show the called sub-category. Any Idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got your blog posts to show only 10?

```
Settings -> Reading -> 'Blog pages show at most'
```

Comment: SMacFadyen. That's was exactly what the problem was. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. You may be able to overwrite the general setting within the core-code that you have for E-commerce, as I imagine it will have somewhere posts_per_page.